# Import Shadows Type from MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, material-ui

We have Typescript in our project that's picky about the use of `any`, and we have a line of code: `const shadowArray: any = Array(25).fill('none')` borrowed from elsewhere on StackOverflow I believe.

This is functioning, but I'd like to corral the `any` to the proper `Shadows` type from MaterialUI, but can't find where to import it from. I do see an export of `shadows` (https://material-ui.com/system/shadows/#shadows) but it's not the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import it from [`@material-ui/core/styles/shadows.d.ts`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/51b6ea9626a1be8304e495b39cd9ed6ca1ce5c0d/packages/material-ui/src/styles/shadows.d.ts#L1):

```
import { Shadows } from '@material-ui/core/styles/shadows';

...

const shadowArray: Shadows = Array(25).fill('none')
```

Edit: In MUI v5 `Shadows` can be imported with `import { Shadows } from '@mui/material/styles'`

Comment: Minor correction to `Shadows`, not `Shadow`, but yes this worked thanks!